# How to update two tables at a time using a single stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have two tables in my database `Requests` and `Balance` tracker which has no relation.... but I want to select data from two tables and bind it two grid...

Requests

```
EmpID | EmpRqsts | EmpDescription | ApproverID | ApprovedAmount | RequestPriority
   1  | asdfsb   | sadbfsbdf      |     1      |
   2  | asbfd    | sjkfbsd        |     1      |
```

Balance Tracker

```
EmpId | BalanceAmnt | LastUpdated | lastApprovedAmount
  1   |    5000     | sdfbk       |
  2   |    3000     | sjbfsh      |
```

Now I want to update both tables at a time, based on the `EmpID`. Whenever amount is approved, it should be updated in `request` table column `[ApprovedAmount]` and with priority...

When `[ApprovedAmount]` is updated [BalanceAmnt] Balance Tracker  of also should be Updated by adding the amount approved,[LastUpdated],[lastApprovedAmount] should be updated with date and time

Can anyone help me with the query please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a stored procedure to update your `[ApprovedAmount]` column

```
create procedure SP_UpdateRequestedAmount
    (@EmpID int,
     @AmountApproved varchar (50),
     @RequestPriority varchar (50))
as
begin
    Update Requests   
    set ApprovedAmount = @AmountApproved,
        Request_Priority = @RequestPriority 
    where
        Emp_ID = @EmpID
end
```

Then use a triger to update the other table when ever [AmountApproved] column is updated

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ApprovedAmount_UPDATE 
ON Requests   
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
    --Make sure Priority was changed 
    IF NOT UPDATE(ApprovedAmount) 
        RETURN 

    --Determine if Priority was changed to high 

    -- PUT your queries for Updatating other table 
     declare @Balance_LastUpdated date
     declare @ApprovedDate date

     UPDATE Balance Tracker
     SET Balance Tracker.Balance_BalanceAmount =  Balance Tracker.Balance_BalanceAmount +   PTS_Requests.Request_IsApproved,
         Balance_LastUpdated = @Balance_LastUpdated,
         Balance_LastApproval = @ApprovedDate
     FROM
         Balance Tracker 
     INNER JOIN
         Requests ON Balance Tracker.Emp_ID = Requests.Emp_ID
```

Hope this helps.........

Answer (score 0):

Please try this also with out trigger

```
    CREATE procedure SP_UpdateRequestedAmount
   (
   @EmpID int,
   @AmountApproved varchar (50),
   @RequestPriority varchar (50)
   )
   as
   begin

   --Declare a variable for know current ApprovedAmount (that is before updation)
   Declare @CurrentApprovedAmount AS INT

   --set current ApprovedAmount
   SET @AmountApproved =(SELECT ApprovedAmount FROM Requests WHERE EmpID=@EmpID)

   --check is @CurrentApprovedAmount differ from @AmountApproved
   IF (@CurrentApprovedAmount!=@AmountApproved)
        BEGIN
                --Here we need to update  Requests and BalanceTracker
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            --only update Requests -- no change in AmountApproved
        END 

   go
```